# How to save an image to a folder and save that link to a mySQL database

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

I have created a java web application in netbeans for a college project. I have read that saving images to a folder is more efficient than using BLOB files. However, I am finding it difficult to find a simple example that works online. Would someone please be able to send me in the right direction :)

Answer (score 0):

New a map of `picId`/`picPath`, use `java.io` upload to setr, then insert the path.